# How to move Focus from a Text input field to the first LI of an UL?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I'm trying to move the mouse focus from a text field to the first LI of an UL which appears right below the text field. I'd like to be able to scroll up/down the list and ENTER to select an entry/row. After the ENTER key is hit, some values from the row are used to populate the other fields.

The text field has the onKeyUp trigger on it, which makes things a little bit tricky. I need this trigger as I need to query the database as the user types.

The result I'd like to achieve is similar to google.com search. If you go to google.com in Firefox you see what I mean.

I've tried something like

```
$("#myUL").find('li').first().focus().addClass('some-class');
```

but it didn't work.

How can I move the focus to the UL?

Here's my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/98xUZ/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So when I type "m" the focus on the input is lost, and I'm really annoyed as I was going to type "moron", but every time I type a character the focus shifts to the damn UL and after typing three characters in the search field I leave your website forever in an uncontrollable rage over the moron who designed that crappy UX.

Comment: @Roobie, why are you struggling to try and reinvent the wheel? why not just use [jQueryUI Auto Complete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: Hi Pete. That looks cool - I wasn't aware of it. Will have a closer look. Cheers for that!

Comment: With this jQueryUI Auto complete, can I select a row and autopopulate more than one fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this in function :

```
function buildList(pThis) {

//    console.log(window.event.keyCode + " is pressed");

    var ul = $('#stnUL');
    var li = "";
    ul.empty('li');

    loc = dataObj.locations;

    li = '<li class="liHeading"><span class="liLocId">LocID</span><span class="liLocName">Name</span></li>';

    $.each(loc, function (i, o) {

        li += '<li tabindex="' + i + '" class="liLocList" onMouseOver="javascript:mOver(this);" onMouseOut="javascript:mOut(this);"><span class="liLocId">' + loc[i].locId + '</span><span class="liLocName">' + loc[i].name + '</span></li>';

    });

    $(ul).append(li);
    var itemPosArr = getItemBottomLeft(pThis.id);
    displayUL('ulDiv', itemPosArr[0], itemPosArr[1]);
    $("#ulDiv").show();
     $( "ul li" ).first().removeClass().css("background-color", "");   
    $( "ul li" ).first().addClass('active');

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats one part of it. How about navigate (arrow up/down) the list? What jquery method/s I need to use?

Comment: yes you r right pete, its can be used but i just tried to make it custom autocomplete functionality by jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code AshishHashCoder: $( "ul li" ).first().removeClass().css("background-color", "");       $( "ul li" ).first().addClass('active'); I've been able to expand it further to tailor my need.

Answer (score 0):

For the up/down arrow piece, you generally want to avoid coding to those events if you can help it. Best option is setting tabindex attribute on the li tags and responding to the focus events.